# Blog created with ExpressJS backed by MongoDB not showing posts from DB

Tags: mongodb, express, pug

I've created a very simple blog web app with ExpressJS and MongoDB. But the index page doesn't render the 'blogPosts' that I input into the DB. It only shows the title as "BL's Blog", without any posts below.

Why aren't the posts showing?

app.js:

```js
//Module dependencies
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

//Mongodb
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/hello-express/');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

//GET
app.get('/', routes.index(db));
app.get('/users', user.list);
app.get('/userlist', routes.userlist(db));
app.get('/newuser', routes.newuser);

//POST
app.post('/adduser', routes.adduser(db));

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

routes/index.js(I only included exports.index as it's the relevant route to this problem):

```js
exports.index = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {
        var posts = db.get('blogPosts');
        posts.find({}, {}, function(e, docs) {
            res.render('index', {
                "index": docs
            });
        });
    };
};
```

views/index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        BL's Blog
    ul
        - each post in index
            li
                h3 = post.title
                p = post.content
```

Comment: Is data being returned by the call to `find`? You should be able to narrow the problem down more.

Comment: @WiredPrairie If you are referring to the mongo console, when I run a db.blogPosts.find(), it returns the data which I input earlier.

Comment: No, not the MongoDB console, from within the `index` function. Maybe just add `console.log(docs)`

Comment: @WiredPrairie I added it in but the console returned nothing. docs is undefined when I try to access it in the Javascript console of chrome...

Comment: @xbili `e` isn't there to be ignored ;)

Comment: When I consoloe.log docs, an empty array is returned. When I console.log e, a null value is returned. So now I assume that it's not pulling any data from MongoDB?

Comment: Confirm you're connecting to the correct database when looking at the data in the mongodb console. You'd: `use hello-express`

Comment: @WiredPrairie Yup! I just realised that too. In index.js I should db.get('hello-express') instead too right?

Comment: Yes, you'd want to do that consistently, and ideally pass the DB instance to your other pages.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Well yeap I changed it as such, and Terminal now shows that data is being pulled from mongo. But the page still isn't showing the posts. Could it be a problem with my index.jade?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Okay I think I just solved my own problem, thanks for the help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I have actually found out the answer to my own question, thanks to the help of **WiredPrairie**.

The first problem lies with the **name of the database** that I'm using. Thus in my index.js, it should have been:

```
exports.index = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {
        var posts = db.get('hello-express'); //Here's the difference.
        posts.find({}, {}, function(e, docs) {
            res.render('index', {
                "index": docs
            });
        });
    };
};
```

I listed in app.js that I'm using the database called 'hello-express' with this line below:

```
var db = monk('localhost:27017/hello-express/');
```

Hence the name of database being used should be named as 'hello-express'.

**However, even after doing so, I could not render the Jade page properly.** This was due to a syntax error (I know, I'm new.)

```
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        BL's Blog
    ul
        - each post in index
            li
                h3 #{post.title}
                p #{post.content}
```

By using `#{<var>}` instead of `=`, the page was able to render properly. I still have no idea why this is the case, but at least it has solved my problem for now.